# Camera in a Container view

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8

I am making an app in Xcode 8 using swift 3. Its a tabbed view application. For one of its tab I want a camera interface. so whenever that tab loads I need to show the camera. I want tab bar to stay there permanent, so I took a container view.  I am using ImagepickerController and loading the Camera in ViewDidAppear method. so camera loads along with tab click. The problem is I wanted camera in that specific container size. But UIImageviewcontroller is making the interface in a full screen. Is there any way to force it to that container size or custom camera is the only option?

Comment: To achieve this you need to create custom camera layer.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible using UIImagePickerController. From the documentation:

> **Present the user interface.**
>
> On iPhone or iPod touch, do this modally (full-screen) by calling the present(_:animated:completion:) method of the currently active view controller, passing your configured image picker controller as the new view controller.

I'm afraid you need to read this:

> **Fully-Customized Media Capture and Browsing**
>
> To perform fully-customized image or movie capture, instead use the AV Foundation framework as described in [Still and Video Media Capture](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/AVFoundationPG/Articles/00_Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010188-CH1-SW10). Camera access using the AV Foundation framework is available starting in iOS 4.0.

Comment: Thanks If I couldn't do it using UIImagePickerController I will use AVFoundation and custom camera

Answer (score 0):

Try to not use ImagepickerController as the tabbarController's item, just use a UIViewController as item, and the ImagepickerController's view added to the UIViewController's view. so that you can controll the contain size by you self.

```
[self addChildViewController:self.imagepickerController];

[self.view addSubview:self.imagepickerController.view];

//do something like layout the self.imagepickerController.view at here

[self.imagepickerController didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: My application is a tabbed view so I cannot get rid of tab bar. so I am taking a separate view controller and  I am putting code you showed in viewDidLoad method. Also I want to load camera as view loads so I am presenting the imagepicker in viewDidAppear method. Now I am taking a container in a tabview so, i can load this UIview controller in a tabview(main).

Comment: Now the problem is instead of showing camera it showing photo library. Initially it crashed because I had not added NSphoto librarry usage description. So i added to see what happens and Now it shows the photo library instead of camera and then it crashes. I dont understand how its possible.

Comment: The reason for crashing again is Terminating app due to uncaught exception "'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Application tried to present modally an active controller".